# Spanning Tree Operation when Bridging Networks on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, bridge

I am connecting two cables from two switches to my Windows Server 2008 machine. The ports are configured as access ports on the switch ports and are in the same VLAN. I want to setup basic redundancy on the Windows Server. I enable the bridge and everything seems to work as expected. However, I believe Windows is running the Spanning Tree Protocol (STP). On my switches, both ports show as Forwarding. That means either a loop is going on, or that Windows took care of making one interface behave in discarding/blocking state.

I would really like to disable STP on Windows so that it lets the BPDUs flow in the bridge. I want my switch to operate STP, not Windows. Does anyone have a clue on how to configure STP on Windows?

This question is about a very specific issue. I am not looking for alternative solutions other than an STP-based one. **I cannot implement any form of NIC Teaming on the server.**

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

I found out these posts:

http://www.networking-forum.com/viewtopic.php?t=26452
http://reggle.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/hidden-feature-in-windows-7-spanning-tree/

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why don't you just use your NIC vendor's tools to configure whatever kind of bonding or failover you're trying to do?

Comment: Why are you bridging? you just want teaming don't you?

Comment: Actually, I am connecting both ports on two different switches and they don't support 802.3ax/802.3ad for Link Aggregation/NIC Teaming. That's why I'm hoping to use RSTP to provide a failover mechanism.

Comment: Clarify your question, because it currently says "I am connecting two cables from a switch". Your comment says it's two switches (and you don't say how you're linking the switches, which might be relevant.)

Comment: Bridging is intended to bridge two different network segments together. I'm assuming then that these two switches aren't connected to each other (if they are you're doing it wrong and you have no need to bridge the network connections in Windows). As such, no loop exists. Windows is bridging the two networks together. There's only one connection between Windows and each of the switches and so each switch port that Windows is connected to should be in the Forwarding state.

Comment: @mfinni: Sorry for that, the switches are indeed connected together. I will add a topology drawing shortly.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Please see the drawing above.

Comment: Is one of the ports connecting the switches together in the Discarding/Blocking state? If so, then no loop exists.

Comment: @joeqwerty: Of course, the links are all in forwarding mode. This is the whole point of this question. Windows is running Spanning Tree and blocks the ports on its bridge accordingly.

Comment: You said both ports were in the Forwarding state. I assumed you meant the two ports that the Windows server is connected to. You also have the two ports that connect the switches to each other. If those are both in the Forwarding state then Windows does have one of its NIC's in the Discarding/Blocking state. I was merely asking if you checked the two ports that connect the two switched together.

Comment: This is almost certainly not what you want to do. By bridging between the two switches, you risk causing all network traffic to transit your server, which could easily overwhelm it. As mfinni and Chopper3 noted, NIC teaming is what you want. It isn't just for link aggregation. Most teaming software can also operate in active/standby or transmit load-balancing modes, which do not require any intelligence on the switch side.

Comment: @JamesSneeringer: It's very good to know that there exist such operation mode that doesn't need the switch to be aware. I was not familiar with them. However, I do have a very specific industrial application in which I cannot install full network drivers that include NIC Teaming settings. If the STP operates as it should, no traffic is ever going to flow across the bridge. I'm still looking for an answer to my initial question, but I am beginning to understand there might not be one. Thank you for taking the time to answer.